# Find all natural numbers such that $\sqrt{n+2020}+\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

My attempt:

$\sqrt{n+2020}+\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{N} $$\Rightarrow $$\frac{2020}{\sqrt{n+2020}-\sqrt{n}} \in \mathbb{N} $

$\Rightarrow $$\sqrt{n+2020}-\sqrt{n}=w \in \mathbb{N} $in which w is a factor of$ 2020$

Note( w is even, you can chek this by separating the cases)

$2020=5×2^2×101$,

so the factor of $2020$ is $5^{i}×2^{j}×101^{k}$ which ($0\leq i\leq 1 $ and $ 0\leq k\leq 1 $ and $0 \leq j\leq2$)

So $i=k={0,1}$ and $j={0,1,2}$

So the numbers of factor of 2020 is $j×k×i=3×2×2=12$

After that we can see $(i, k, j)$ maybe equal this values

$(i, k, j) ={(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(0,1,2),(1,0,0) ,(1,0,1),(1,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,2)}$

If $(i, k, j) =(0, 0,0)$that implie $w=1 $ that is impossible because we know w is even

If $(i, k, j) =(0, 0,1)$that implie $w=2 $

If $(i, k, j) =(0, 0,2)$that implie $w=4 $

If $(i, k, j) =(0, 1,0)$that implie $w=101 $ that is impossible because we know w is even

So  i  check the  all above values, and in final i  find just 8 value of w and this value is $w={2,4,202,404,10,20,1010,2020}$

After that  suppose $n+2020=x^2$ and $n=y^2$ wich$ x, y \in \mathbb{N} $

After the last assumation we can see Two results, the first is $x+y$ is even is easy the chek that
And the seconde results is $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)=2020$

And $x-y=w$

So if $x-y=w=2$$\Rightarrow$ $x+y=1010 $ So$ x+y+x-y=2x=1012$

So $x=506$

if $x-y=w=4$$\Rightarrow $$x+y=505$ that is impossible because $x+y$ is even

if$x-y=w=202$$\Rightarrow $$x+y=10$

So $x=106$

And i am continued like, and in final, I find just $x=106$ and $x=506$

So if $x=506 $ that implie $n=506^2-2020=254016$

if $x=106 $ that implie $n=106^2-2020=9216$

So finally:

$n=9216$

And

$n=254016$

So what are you think about my attempt, is true or false?

Any comment is acceptable

Comment: The first line is suspect. 2020/ (1.5) is an integer, but 1.5 is not an integer.

Comment: How do you conclude $\frac{2020}{\sqrt{n+2020}-\sqrt{n}} \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \sqrt{n+2020}-\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{N}$?  For example, how do you eliminate the possibility $\sqrt{n+2020}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{2020}{2019}$?  (The easiest way I can think of uses some mildly advanced number theory: $\sqrt{n+2020}-\sqrt{n}$ is both an algebraic integer and rational, therefore it's an integer.)

Comment: Why must $ w$ be a factor of 2020? All you have is 2020/w  is an integer. Why can't $ w = 1.5$?

Comment: @Calvin lin because of w=1,5 2020/1,5 =1346,6 isnt a natural number

Comment: Oh oops, 2020/2.5 = 808. Can $ w = 2.5$?

Comment: I think my approach would be more like: if you set $a := \sqrt{n+2020}$ and $b := \sqrt{n}$ which must both be integers (again since they're rational by a similar argument and they're also algebraic integers), then $(a-b) (a+b) = a^2 - b^2 = 2020$.  Throw in that $a-b$ and $a+b$ have the same parity so they must both be even, and from each factorization of $\frac{2020}{4}$ you should be able to work backwards to find a solution.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Right, the key is to get to $ n+2020, n$ are both perfect squares. This is true in general for $ \sum \sqrt{a_i}$ via a high power theorem, but can also be shown in small 2-term cases by repeated squaring.

Comment: @Calvin lin yes you are right w maybe equal 2,5,so that is my mistake

Comment: You can deduce $\sqrt{n+2020}-\sqrt n\in \Bbb{Q} $ with your argument, then it's easy to see that both square roots must be rational as well, they're rational if they are both squares of rationals, but since they are integers they must be squares of integers.

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in the comments, the first step is false.

(Though the subsequent conclusions are true, so we just need to fix this first step.)

---

**Hint:** Show that if $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ \sqrt{k} \in \mathbb{N}$, then $ k = a^2$ for some $ a \in \mathbb{N}$.

After proving the hint, apply it to show that $n$ and $n+2020$ are both perfect squares.

> Show that if $ \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{ n+2020} = k \in \mathbb{N}$, then consider $ n+2020 = k^2 - 2k\sqrt{n} + n $ to prove that $(4k^2n) = a^2$ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}$, and so $ n = b^2$ for some $b\in \mathbb{N}$.
>  Likewise, $ n+2020 = c^2$ for some $ c \in \mathbb{N}$.

The rest of your proof then follows.

Comment: Okey sir, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want: $n = p^2, n+2020 = q^2\implies q^2 -p^2 = 2020\implies (q-p)(q+p)=2020$. Observe that both $q-p, q+p$ must be even. Thus looking at the prime factorization of $2020 = 2^2\cdot 5\cdot 101$. Thus it must be that $q-p = 2, q+p = 1010\implies q = 506, p = 504\implies n = 504^2 $, or $q-p = 10, q+p = 202 \implies q = 106, p = 96$ which gives $n = 96^2$. Thus there are two solutions: $n = 96^2, 504^2$.

Comment: IMO Getting to the first line is the hard part of the proof. What you listed out was done by OP.

Comment: Yes sir thank you

Comment: $n=96^2$ is also a solution, so your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @jjagmath: Thanks for pointing out the incompleteness.